# Convert string to list of mixed float, int and str knowing the format in Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, python-2.7, formatter

Consider a simple string like `'1.5 1e+05 test 4'`. The format used in Python 2.7 to generate that string is `'%f %e %s %i'`. I want to retrieve a list of the form `[1.5,100000,'test',4]` from my input string knowing the string formatter. How can I do that (Python 2.7 or Python 3)?

Thanks a lot,

Ch.

Comment: `import parse, format_string='{:1f} {:.2e} {:s} {:d}'
pn=format_string.format(1.5,100000,'test',4)
parsed=parse.parse(format_string, pn)`  Does not work

Comment: Did you download and install the `parse` module?

Comment: Yes well of course, in my case `type(parsed)` is `NoneType`

Comment: Have you considered [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)?

Comment: In your format string, replace `{:s}` with `{}`. For some reason this works

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That's generally a bad idea, unless you absolutely need it

Comment: @Jerfov2 How so?  `literal_eval` is safe, unlike `eval`

Comment: @Jerfov2 Thanks for the tip, it works well, this remains however a mystery why `{:s}` didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `parse` module. This module can do 'reverse formatting'. Example:

```
from parse import parse

format_str = '{:1f} {:.2e} {} {:d}' 
data = [1.5, 100000, 'test', 4]
data_str = format_str.format(*data)
print(data_str) # Output: 1.500000 1.00e+05 test 4
parsed = parse(format_str, data_str)
print(parsed) # Output: <Result (1.5, 100000.0, 'test', 4) {}>
a, b, c, d = parsed # Whatever
```

Comment: @ChrisB You're welcome! If you liked the answer, accept it